Linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ and $\dim V=3$, and $T^3=0$. If $T^2(v)\neq 0$, how do I prove that $dim$ {$v$,$T(v)$,$T^2(v)$}$=3$?
As mention in title:

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ and $\dim V=3$, and $T^3=0$. If $T^2(v)\neq 0$, how do I prove that $$\dim \{v,T(v),T^2(v)\}=3$$

I've been trying to tackle this problem left and right, but I have no idea where to begin. I thought of using a counterexample first, in a case where $T^2(v)=0$, but I'm not sure where to go from there if that is the correct decision. If $T:V\rightarrow V$, and $\dim V=3$, doesn't that mean a group of three vectors in such a space will also make $\dim V=3$?

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

What can you say about the equation $c_0 v + c_1 T(v) + c_2 T^2 (v) = 0$?

Which condition has to hold for three vectors if they span a three dim sub space?

As mention in the comment section, consider $c_0v+c_1T(v)+c_2T^2(v)=0$, thus we need to show $c_0=c_1=c_2=0$.
Apply the fact that $T^3=0$ and $T^2(v)\neq0$:
$$\begin{align}
c_0v+c_1T(v)+c_2T^2(v)=0&\implies T(c_0v+c_1T(v)+c_2T^2(v))=T(0)\\
&\implies c_0T(v)+c_1T^2(v)+c_2T^3(v)=0\\
&\implies c_0T(v)+c_1T^2(v)=0\\
&\implies c_0T^2(v)=0\\
&\implies c_0=0
\end{align}$$
Showing $c_1,c_2=0$ are easy, so I will leave it to you.
